# What NP-complete problem to reduce to k-Edge-Colorability to prove its NP-hardness?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, reductions, np-hard

What known NP-complete problem would one reduce to $k$-Edge-Colorability to prove that the latter is NP-hard?

Comment: 1) What have you tried and where did you get stuck? 2) *Any one*. 3) Such a reduction only shows NP-hardness, not -completeness.

Comment: I just want to know that! I said "as a proof for it's NP-completeness" and it means this reduction is part of a proof for NP-Completeness and definitely as another part we must show that It's an NP Problem.

Comment: @Raphael 2) Sure but the question is still meaningful: reducing something graph-related is going to be much easier than reducing some obscure scheduling problem.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That would make the question inherently subjective, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic result of Holyer [1]. The reduction is from 3-SAT, and the constructed graph is cubic.

---

[1] [Holyer, Ian. "The NP-completeness of edge-coloring." SIAM Journal on Computing 10.4 (1981): 718-720.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.97.5480&rep=rep1&type=pdf)